# Visiting Salmon Glacier, near Stewart, British Columbia (Canada)/Hyder, Alaska (USA)

Tags: driving, borders, alaska, british-columbia, glaciers

Near the southernmost point of the British Columbia, Canada/Alaska, USA border is a [beautiful glacier named Salmon Glacier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salmon_Glacier).  Apparently this glacier can be visited using a gravel road from the town of Stewart, BC, via Hyder, Alaska.

Have any of you driven this route?  Can it be done in a sedan?  I have driven fairly rough roads in my car before (e.g. Gap Road between the centre and west blocks of Cypress Hills Interprovincial Park in Alberta/Saskatchewan) and not had any problems.  But this territory is a lot more remote and it would be more difficult to get help.

The route is interesting because one has to first enter the U.S., then drive back to Canada.  No border stations are encountered until one crosses again on the way back, between Hyder and Stewart.  (The US has no posts at all on this part of the border.)

Comment: I've found a [blog article on this road here](http://explorenorth.com/wordpress/granduc-road-salmon-glacier-beyond/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did it with a couple of friends last year (in a Camry 2010). Oh my! That was fantastic! 
The road from Hyder is definitely washboardy and there's a bunch of cracks and potholes you have to dodge... If you don't rush it, that should be ok! Anyway, you're going to have an amazing time, enjoy :)